# Remove fancyhdr chapter 0 header

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer, chapters, fancyhdr

I use the `fancyhdr` package, so as to include the name and number of the relevant chapter in the header. This is my code:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{#1}}
\fancyhead[R]{}
\fancyhead[L]{\chaptername\ \thechapter\ --\ \leftmark}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter*{Introduction}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}
Text
\newpage
More text

\chapter{The first chapter}

\end{document}
```

As you perceive, the introduction is not enumerated.

With the code above, the second page of the introduction is given a header with the text "Chapter 0 - CONTENTS".

The same thing happens if the table of contents goes beyond the first page. Subsequent pages are all given the same header.

How could I adjust the above code, so that the headers are only introduced with the first chapter, and the table of contents and introduction are without a header?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use a different approach, namely to set the header in `\chaptermark`.

```latex
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{} % clear the headers
\fancyhead[L]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\chaptername\ \thechapter\ -- #1}{}}

\newcommand{\uchapter}[1]{%
  \chapter*{#1}%
  \markboth{#1}{}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\uchapter{Introduction}

Text
\newpage
More text

\chapter{The first chapter}

Text
\newpage
More text

% check the header of a possible second page in the TOC
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\newpage\protect\mbox{}}

\end{document}
```

The `\nouppercase` is needed because `report` adds `\MakeUppercase` to the arguments to `\markboth` for special chapters such as the TOC, the lists of figures and tables and the bibliography.

I introduced a `\uchapter` command to avoid heavy code in the document body.

Comment: Delete my answer and I upvoted your.

Comment: (offtopic) is possible to find on StackExchange the same solution for `article`?

Answer (score 3):

Change the `\fancyhead[L]{...}` to

```
\makeatletter
\fancyhead[L]{%
  % thank egreg for his help in comment
  \ifnum\value{chapter}=0\else\chaptername\ \thechapter\ --\ \fi\leftmark
}
\makeatother
```

and add

```
\chaptermark{Introduction}
```

after `\chapter*{Introduction}` help.

With this change,

- the second page of unnumbered chapter "Introduction" will have its left header showing "Introduction", and
- the second page of table of contents will have its left header showing "CONTENTS".

A full example

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{#1}}
\fancyhead[R]{}

\makeatletter
\fancyhead[L]{%
  % thank egreg for his help in comment
  \ifnum\value{chapter}=0\else\chaptername\ \thechapter\ --\ \fi\leftmark
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter*{Introduction}
\chaptermark{Introduction}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}
Text
\newpage
More text

\chapter{The first chapter}
\newpage
text

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\ifnum\c@chapter` is better; even more so `\ifnum\value{chapter}`; `\the` is innocuous in that position, it could be harmful in different cases.

Comment: @egreg Thank you. Answer is updated to use `\ifnum\value{chapter}` instead of `\ifnum\the\c@chapter`.

Comment: Many thanks. This works very well for the sections preceding the first chapter. However, I still have one problem: The sections that follow the final chapter all retain the header of the final chapter; *e.g.* if we add: `\chapter*{Conclusion}  Concluding text  \newpage  Conclusively concluding text`. The second page of the conclusion has the same header: "Chapter 1 - The first chapter". How could one change this?

Comment: @HeinrichWagner Use another `\chaptermark` to set the text in header.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ That works. Thanks. But what if the final chapter is followed by a bibliography? *E.g* the following: `\chapter{Final chapter} Text \newpage \nocite{*} \printbibliography`. Then the header of the bibliography will be "Chapter X - Bibliography". How can I remove the "Chapter X" bit?

Comment: @HeinrichWagner egreg's answer automatically meets your requirement. My answer is too special to be suitable for general use.